# How to add IPv6 static route via host on other network?

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I have a bunch of IPv6-only hosts in location A. To let them connect to IPv4-only hosts, I have set up a NAT64 gateway on a dual-stack host in location B. Now I want the IPv6-only hosts in location A to forward all traffic for the `64:ff9b::/96` network to the NAT64 gateway in location B.

When I try to add a static route like this, I get the following error message:

```sh
$ sudo ip -6 route add 64:ff9b::/96 via 2001:db8::
RTNETLINK answers: No route to host
```

What do I need to do to forward traffic for the `64:ff9b::/96` network to the host `2001:db8::`?

Comment: What's an example Location-A host IP? The gateway `2001:db8::` needs to be in a subnet attached to the host. You probably want to add that route to the default gateway for Location A instead of the hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly add routes via hosts on other networks, in general. Routes work by altering the *link-layer* address of packets, and those by definition are only possible to set within the local network – as soon as the packet needs to go through a router, there's no longer any place in the packet to specify the desired gateway.

(IPv6 does have "Routing Headers", similar to how IPv4 had "Source Route" options, but the closest thing that does what you want – RH [type 0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5095.html) – has been ripped out of implementations due to being a major security risk, exactly like IPv4 source routing before it. The remaining RH types, such as Segment Routing, require setup along the entire path.)

So in order to make this work you'll need to set up a tunnel (e.g. a GRE tunnel or WireGuard VPN) with the remote gateway as the tunnel endpoint, then route your packets through that tunnel.